# Value is not null when math result is < decided value in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a Postgresql function where i first check if the row already exists using IF IS NULL. later on in the function i have another if statement to check whether or not a math result is above a certain number and if yes make some changes.
The weird thing is that when the number is lower then the first IF statement becomes not null and then does not work at all.
When the number is above then the function works properly.
[This is the insert and error]

[image: 1]
[This is the function query]

[image: 2]

Comment: please paste the code instead of screenshots

Comment: also clearly if the_quiz id is not null and  correct/total is not greater than  0.6 , then you function doesn't return anything and that's where you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eshirvana pointed out not all branches in your function return a value. Just move the last `RETURN did_insert` statement below the `END IF` on line 30 so that no matter what branching conditions you always return a value

Comment: I cant believe that was the solution. So simple! I am still new to all this so things are a little unclear and confusing. Thank you.